# How to disable explicit proxy on chocolatey?

Tags: proxy, chocolatey

I enabled explicit proxy on chocolatey with this command in windows cmd:

```
choco config set proxy http://localhost:8888
```

Now I want to disable it but don't know how.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you issued the command:

`choco config set proxy http://localhost:8888`

What actually happened was that Chocolatey updated the chocolatey.config file located in `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\config\chocolatey.config`.  You should actually be able to compare between the current config file, and the backup version which should be at the same location.

To reverse this action, simply run the command:

`choco config unset proxy`

Have a look at the examples which are shown when you run:

`choco config -h`

for more information.